# Javascript is not able to access variable inside class

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, class

My AJAX call display this table.

```
?>
<tr bgcolor='white'>
<td bgcolor='white'width='5%'><input type=checkbox name=chekboxTopic[] value=<?php echo '$projectId' ?> </td>

</tr>
<?php
```

I am accessing the checkbox variable from my javascript without any problem.

```
var ProjectId = checkboxes[i].value;
```

I moved the table to a class and called it to show the table successfully.

```
      class showtable{
                function showcontent($chapterId) 
                        {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

        $projectId = $row['projectid']; 
            ?>        
            <tr bgcolor='white'>

            <td bgcolor='white'width='5%'><input type=checkbox name=chekboxTopic[] value=<?php echo '$projectId' ?> </td>

            </tr>
            <?php
                                              }
                         }
                     }
```

But now my java script is not able to access this checkbox variable.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: show your code after move table in class or make fiddle

Comment: Thanks, Class was added to the question.

Comment: by building your html/input in a php class, it will not change how your javascript interacts with it, unless you php results in invalid code. Look at your html source code **after** page load and see what has changed.

Comment: Divyesh, I have proper escape for php. I edited the question. Sean, you cleared the doubt. I will try to see any differences. thouhg source doesn't show the AJAX called content.

Comment: I coppied and pasted table to the class. working. something in typing. thanks all..